# Extract specific variables in Excel via a Matlab GUI

Tags: excel, matlab, functional-programming, matlab-guide

I have created a *GUI* in ***Matlab***  which after some calculations it displays in the workspace various variables, for example *mass, density, height, power and speed*.

My first problem is that I have a pushbutton which I want to let me save the above data in an ***Excel*** file with the following format:

1. mass, density and height are in defferent sheets
2. power and speed are in the same sheet next to each other

Whatever I tried it didn't work, that's why i paste only the function from the *GUI*:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
```

My second problem is that i have a pushbutton which i want to let me save whichever of the above variabes i want in an ***Excel*** file and I tried the following:

```
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
    [filename, pathname] = uiputfile('*.xls', 'Choose a file name'); 
    outname = fullfile(pathname, filename); 
    xlswrite(outname, M);
```

I want everytime I run the *GUI* to have the ability to set M with the name of the variable i want to extract, e.g. density.

Can someone help me with the above?

Τhanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion `xlswrite` is not a good pick for the first part of your question, because if you want to handle two different variables being written on the same sheet asynchronously, it won't let you append data on an existing sheet of an existing file. You have to use Excel interoperability instead through an `actxserver` instance (refer to [this page](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-a-matlab-application-as-an-automation-client.html) for more information).

Here is how to save everything to file:

```
[filename,pathname] = uiputfile('*.xls', 'Choose a File'); 

if (~filename)
    errordlg('Invalid file name specified.');
end

e = actxserver('Excel.Application');
e.DisplayAlerts = false;
e.Visible = false;

wb = e.Workbooks.Add();
shts = e.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets;

sht1 = shts.Item(1);
sht1.Activate();
sht1.Name = 'Density';
sht1.Range(['A1:A' num2str(numel(D))]).Value = D; % your Density variable

sht2 = shts.Item(2);
sht2.Activate();
sht2.Name = 'Height';
sht2.Range(['A1:A' num2str(numel(H))]).Value = H; % your Height variable

sht3 = shts.Item(3);
sht3.Activate();
sht3.Name = 'Mass';
sht3.Range(['A1:A' num2str(numel(M))]).Value = M; % your Mass variable

shts.Add([],shts.Item(shts.Count));
sht4 = shts.Item(4);
sht4.Activate();
sht4.Name = 'Other';
sht4.Range(['A1:A' num2str(numel(P))]).Value = P; % your Power variable
sht4.Range(['B1:B' num2str(numel(S))]).Value = S; % your Speed variable

wb.SaveAs(fullfile(pathname,filename));
wb.Close();

e.Quit();
delete(e);
```

Now... for what concerns the second part of your question, the initial pattern is almost the same, with the addition of an [inputdlg](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputdlg.html) for choosing the proper variable to save. In this case you could use `xlswrite` since it's a one-shot call for handling everything:

```
variable = cell2mat(inputdlg('Enter the variable name to be saved:','Choose a Variable'));

switch (variable)
    case 'Density'
        data = D;
    case 'Height'
        data = H;
    case 'Mass'
        data = M;
    case 'Power'
        data = P;
    case 'Speed'
        data = S;
    otherwise
        errordlg('Invalid variable name specified.');
        return;
end

[filename,pathname] = uiputfile('*.xls', 'Choose a File'); 

if (~filename)
    errordlg('Invalid file name specified.');
end

xlswrite(fullfile(pathname,filename),data,variable,'A1');
```

Comment: I tried both in my code but both times it shows the same error "Undefined function or variable 'Density' ", but i can see the variable in workspace. Do you know why this happening?

Comment: Probably a copy-paste error. Check if you didn't miss anything when migrating my code into Matlab.

Comment: I checked it many times, but still doesn't work.The only thing i changed is the range because my  data are not a vector, they are a matrix, I just used  'A1 : ' instead of 'A1 : A', but i don't think thats the problem!

Comment: Missing quotes somewhere maybe?

Comment: The second code works excellent, it was a mispell. The first one still haven't figure out the problem, but i appreciate your help!

Comment: If the error message refers `Display`, try to take a closer look to what's around that word. It appears only once.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: just make multiple calls to `xlswrite` in `pushbutton2_Callback` with the sheet specified. `xlswrite(filename, A, sheet)`. Obviously filename stays the same and A is the data you want on that sheet.

Question 2: It is a little unclear what you are asking, but if you would like to save just one of the selected data points to the file you could make a [uicontrol](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html?s_tid=doc_ta) of listbox style, which has the data types to save. Then, if you wanted to save that type of data to a specific column/row/sheet you would just query its value property (ex. `get(listbox_handle, 'Value')`) and use that to specify sheet and xlrange, which is also an option in the `xlswrite` function. I highly recommend you look at the [doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html#btmdr27-1-sheet) for that function.